# How to overload global new operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

In my application I want to keep only one object of given class with given key. To do so I overrided local new operator in class Base:

```
  void * operator new(size_t size, int k) 
  { 
      return BaseFactory::GetInstance(k);       
  }
```

which calls static method of BaseFactory. This method has a list of existing objects of class Base. If there is already an object with the same key, it returns it, if not it create new object

```
Base* BaseFactory::GetInstance(int k)
{
for(vector<Base*>::iterator it = bases.begin(); it < bases.end(); it++)
    if((*it)->key == k)
        return *it;
//else recognize which object to create on given key. just a simple example
    Base *l = ::new Derived(k);
bases.push_back(l);
return l;
}
```

it works fine but i need to call the function using for example Base* b = new(1) Derived,
while I would like to keep the normal syntax it is Base* b = new Derived(1).
How can I do that, is it possible? I guess overloading global operator might work, I tried

```
void *operator new (size_t size, Base& b, int key)
{
return BaseFactory::GetInstance(key);
}
```

but it doesn't work.
Also right now I am using key to determing which object to create which is OK, since key determines the type of object (deriving from Base) but maybe there is better way.

Also I am open to any other dessing patterns.

Comment: Constructing an object on top of an existing object is a really bad idea.  You probably shouldn't be trying to use a `new` syntax at all.  Just have users call `BaseFactory::GetInstance(k)` or `Base::Get(k)`.

Comment: This is a variant on theme of a Singleton pattern.  However, you probably don't want to throw away whatever is in the existing entry for the key; you want to use that instead of creating a new entry (since it is already constructed).  I think you are tackling the problem in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `new Derived(1)`, the `1` is an argument to the constructor of `Derived`, not to `operator new`.  That's just the way the language does it, sorry.

Comment: so there is no way to do it as I wrote it?